# Mellin transform with compact support

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Mellin transform for $f(x)$ is usually defined as:

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx$$

Is there a Mellin transform with compact support?

For example like
$$F(s,a,b)=\int_a^{b} f(x)x^{s-1}dx,\qquad 0\le a \lt b \le \infty$$

Comment: Well, that *is* the Mellin transform of $f\chi_{[a,b]}$, is it not? What more do you want from it?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. Thanks for the answer. What is $\chi_{[a,b]}$?

Comment: I'd have called this _bounded_ support rather than _finite_ support.  I'd take "finite support" to mean only finitely many points in the support, thus: $\displaystyle F(s)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k k^{s-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\chi_A$ is the characteristic (or [indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)) function of the set $A$: $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.

Comment: Thanks for the information!. Now I also understand this indicator $1_{[0,1]}$